# Cucumber JVM : avoid dependency injection by Picocontainer for features not tagged for execution

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, picocontainer

Assuming that I have a Cucumber feature tagged `@api`

```
@api
Feature: BankID authentication

  Scenario Outline: Successful authentication of user using BankID

    Given the initial flow start URL 
    When  I enter that "<url>" into my browser
    ...
```

and steps for execution as below:

```
public class ApiSteps implements En {
    public ApiSteps (ABCinjected abcInjected) {
        Given("^the initial flow start URL $", () -> {});
        When("^I enter that \"([^\"]*)\" into my browser$", abcInjected::navigateToAuthenticationPage);
        ...
    }
```

Even if I define this feature not to be executed by specifying different Cucumber tags or explicitly specifying  `tags = {"not @api"}` , although steps themselves are not executed per se, Picocontainer still creates and injects instance of ABCinjected class, which is undesirable. Is it possible to control this behavior? I assume if feature is tagged as not to be executed and related scenario/steps are ignored, consecutively DI should not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got response from Cucumber contributor on Github:

> When using lamda steddefs the class has to be instantiated to register
>   the steps. And we would need to know the steps defined by the class to
>   determine if we should instantiate it. This is a dead lock of
>   requirements.

Another recommendation is to set different packages for steps (api, units etc) and set different glue on runtime.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1672